# Getting "405: method not allowed" error while pinging to Jfrog Artifactory in Jfrog CLI

Tags: linux, artifactory, jfrog-cli, jfrog-pipelines

I have Installed Jfrog CLI (2.12.0) and configured it by using `jf config add`command.

After passing the platform URL, username and password I executed  `jf rt ping` to check the connection.

But am getting the below error as a response

```
[root@osc-in-bldslave-1 opt]# jf rt ping
19:13:51 [Error] Server response: 405 Method Not Allowed
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": 405,
      "message": "Method Not Allowed"
    }
  ]
}
```

Please let me know if you need any other details.

Below are the Steps I followed while Jfrog CLI configuration. Correct me if there is any issues with configuration.

```
[root@osc-in-bldslave-1 ~]# jf -version
jf version 2.12.0
[root@osc-in-bldslave-1 ~]#
[root@osc-in-bldslave-1 ~]# jf config add
Choose a server ID : <server id>
JFrog platform URL [http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx:8081/]: http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx:8081/
JFrog access token (Leave blank for username and password/API key):
JFrog username [username]: <username>
JFrog password or API key:<passing password here>
Is the Artifactory reverse proxy configured to accept a client certificate? (y/n) [n]? n
[root@osc-in-bldslave-1 ~]#
[root@osc-in-bldslave-1 ~]# jf rt ping
09:55:13 [Error] Server response: 405 Method Not Allowed
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": 405,
      "message": "Method Not Allowed"
    }
  ]
}
[root@osc-in-bldslave-1 ~]#
```

But if it try pinging to my URL directly using below command it is working fine.

```
[root@osc-in-bldslave-1 ~]# jf rt ping --url=http://172.xx.xxx.xx:8081/artifactory/
OK
```

I deleted and installed Jfrog CLI freshly, still am facing the same 405: method not allowed issue.

Can anyone please let me know what am missing?

Comment: please paste content of `~/.jfrog/jfrog-cli.conf`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like while configuring the JFrog CLI some of the parameters are incorrect, due to which the error is thrown. Same was tested in my env and its workings as expected.

➜  jf -version jf version 2.12.0
➜ jf rt ping OK

Answer (score 0):

you can find using command `which jf` & `whereis jf`